# Can i have 2 function in one script in html?

Tags: javascript, html

My page has a multiple 'tab' which displaying different data.

Here is my function for tab.

```
function openEvt(evt, evtName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(evtName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

My page will display a bar chart when user click 'Detail' tab.
This is my code for the chart.
I put it in the script with the function openEvt().

```
function setChart(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("detail");

    var detail= new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: {{ chartdata_labels|safe }},
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of votes',
            data: {{ chartdata_data }},
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
}

window.onload = setChart;
```

Here is my code for display the chart above a table of data.

```
<canvas id="detail" width="1200" height="400"></canvas>
```

It work fine when there is only one function-openEvt().
But when I add in the setChart(), the tab wont function and no any data is display.

Comment: make sure there are no syntax/logical error in setChart function. Do you have any error in console reported ?. If you can make a jsfiddle, I could help you more.

Comment: No error returned, just can't display any data.

Comment: `labels: {{ chartdata_labels|safe }},`  are you using any template engine? . If not this is a syntax error.

Comment: I have found it! You use double brackets at data.labels, in JavaScript, we use single for those types, so it has to be single {labels:'whatever'} or into an array [{labels:'whatever'}]. Also, you have to define your text at labels, OR is not a choice.

Comment: I using django(python) and display it in html.

Comment: Can you use view-source (Ctrl + U) and update the above code with plain html after framework have rendered ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can! You may add as many as you need, but be careful as it slows load time.

Comment: which one? I assume the bottom.

Comment: ya, setChart function. If I have 2 functions in script, both won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
function SayHello() {
    alert('Hello')
}
function SayWorld() {
    alert('World')
}

function addWindowOnloadEvent(func) {
    var oldWindowOnload = window.onload;
    if (typeof func === 'function') {
        if (typeof window.onload === 'function') {
            window.onload = function () {
                oldWindowOnload();
                func();
            }
        } else {
            window.onload = func;
        }
    }
}

addWindowOnloadEvent(SayHello);
addWindowOnloadEvent(SayWorld);
```